# Get return of a batch file in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a simple batch file return the number of files. I called it and tried to get that return value from Jenkins. However, it was not as expected...
My batch file:

```
@echo off
set count = 0
for /f %%A in ('dir C:\Temp\AutoTestWorkspace\BAT\ ^|find "File(s)"') do set count=%%A
echo %count%
```

My Jenkins code:

```
def total_files = bat ( script: 'D:\\CICD\\MamaBatScript.bat', returnStdout: true)
echo "Total Files is " + total_files
```

The output:

```
Total Files is 
C:\Temp\Jenkins\workspace\AutomationTesting\DispatchTests@2>D:\CICD\MamaBatScript.bat
2
```

I just want to get the number only...In addition, could you please tell me why the output is strange like that...

Answer (score 2):

You should just drop the first line of output.

```
def stdout = bat(returnStdout: true , script: 'D:\\CICD\\MamaBatScript.bat').trim()
def total_files = stdout.readLines().drop(1).join(" ")
```

Comment: I get below error when using readLines... Btw, do you know the reason of the output above?
` Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods readLines java.lang.String. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.`

Comment: goto "Manage Jenkins" -> "In-Process Script Approval" and approve the script.